# Is this integral solvable?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{x_0} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2g(k-\sqrt{l^2+x^2})}}$$

I came across this while doing some physics work, I couldn't solve it using trig. Substitutions or putting $l^2+x^2=t$, and neither could wolfram alpha solve it.

Comment: Is your question just if the integral goes to a real number or what the siolution is? As it stands I guess the first.

Comment: @Ove Ahlman I want to find the solution as a function of x.

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should have a closed form for general values of $l$.

Comment: One possibility to explore is to change variables as $x=l \sinh(t)$. Then, using $1+\sinh^2(t)=\cosh^2(t)$, the inner square root disappears. The resulting integral seems to have a (rather horrible) primitive in terms of Elliptic integrals (Mathematica *docet*). Hope this helps.

Comment: @Travis it would be very disappointing if it didn't have a closed form

Comment: @Pierpaolo Vivo but it shouldn't be this complicated this corresponds to a very simplistic physical model..

Comment: Just because it corresponds to a "simple" physical description, doesn't mean that there exists a standard mathematical function to describe it.

Comment: @Prospect true indeed.

Comment: What's wrong with using that integral as it stands?

Comment: @GEdgar this integral is equal to $\int dt$ on the R.H.S and x as a function of t will represent the law of motion of a particle...

Comment: The expression in terms of elliptic integrals is not sooo ugly. I have seen worse

Comment: By the way, what kind of physical problem are we solving here? Looks like some geodetics in a (Newtonian) gravitational field.

Comment: @tired um actually this was the expression of the motion of a pendulum for any general displacement from mean position

Answer (score 3):

The integral has not a well defined primitive, in terms of simple functions. It's clearly an Elliptic functions integral, and I think it arises by some pendulum problem, doesn't it?

Anyway, I'll try to show you the way to compute it, but **keep in mind** that in the very last part the need of *Mathematica* for the "exact" solution is required. Anyway, the first steps are really trivial.

Starting with taking out of the integral what is a constant, namely $g$ for the moment:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_0^{x_0}\ \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{k - \sqrt{\ell^2 + x^2}}}$$

now substitute

$$x = \ell\sinh\phi$$ so that $$\text{d}x = \ell\cosh\phi\ \text{d}\phi$$

Your extrema will now go from $\ell$ to $\ell\sinh x_0$. Then do the math and you'll get

$$\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{2g}}\int_{\ell}^{\operatorname{arcsinh}(x_0/\ell)}\ \frac{\cosh\phi\ \text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{k - \ell\cosh\phi}}$$

Collecting $k$ and renaming $\frac{\ell}{k} = \ell_0$ you get

$$\frac{\ell}{\sqrt{2gk}}\int_{\ell}^{\operatorname{arcsinh}(x_0/\ell)}\ \frac{\cosh\phi\ \text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{1 - \ell_0\cosh\phi}}$$

And here the simple part ends.
What comes next, is an application of the *Mathematica* software that will lead you to obtain the result in terms of Elliptic functions. I'll give you the unbounded integral result, then it's all about substitution:

$$\color{blue}{\int\frac{\cosh\phi\ \text{d}\phi}{\sqrt{1 - \ell_0\cosh\phi}} = }$$

$$\color{blue}{ = - \frac{2i \cdot\left((\ell_0 - 1)\cdot \mathsf{E}\left[\frac{i\phi}{2}, \frac{2\ell_0}{\ell_0 - 1}\right] + \mathsf{F}\left[\frac{i\phi}{2}, \frac{2\ell_0}{\ell_0 - 1}\right]\right)\sqrt{\frac{\ell_0\cosh\phi - 1}{\ell_0 - 1}}}{\ell_0\sqrt{1 - \ell_0\cosh\phi}}}$$

where we have the Elliptic integral of the Second Kind:

$\mathsf{E}(A, B) = \int_0^A\ \sqrt{1 - B^2\sin^2\theta}\ \text{d}\theta$

and the Elliptic integral of the Fist Kind:

$\mathsf{F}(A, B) = \int_0^A\ \frac{\text{d}\theta}{\sqrt{1 - B^2\sin^2\theta}}$

Now it's your turn to evaluate the result for the given extrema.

**More information about Elliptic integrals here:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral

**More about Elliptic Integral of the First kind here:**

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

**More about Elliptic Integral of the Second Kind here:**

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html

**More about the Pendulum:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)#Arbitrary-amplitude_period

Comment: There's a typo in the upper integration limit of the $\phi$ integral. If $x=x_0$, it follows that $\phi=\mathrm{arcsinh}(x_0/l)$.

Comment: Wow, This is really complicated for me and I don't really understand a lot of it, but thank you for your efforts! (+1)

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Thank you!! I'm going to fix it!

Comment: @Nikunj Don't worry, I bet you will face with Elliptical integrals very soon ^^ It's just experience, nothing really complicated!

Comment: @KimPeek you can cancel the square root in the denominator with the top line of the square root in the numerator and the $-i$ out the front.